# populate the array out of a database

Tags: mysql

//I need an output array from my database,
//I tried:

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM pages";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$aUsers = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

   $row["menu_name"];

}
```

//I need to get something like:

```
$aUsers = array(
        "Ädams Egbert",
        "Altman Alisha",
        "Archibald Janna",
        "Auman Cody",
        "Bagley, Sheree");
```

//I need an array populated with row "menu_name" from table "pages" of my database

//How Can I do this , can somebody help me?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you only need menu_name, you should only select menu_name in the query

```
$query = "SELECT menu_name FROM pages";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$aUsers = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $aUsers[]=$row["menu_name"];

}

print_r($aUsers); //display on page for testing
```

Comment: with this I get the result:Array ( [0] => Agjent për patundshmëri [1] => Elektricist [2] => Moler [3] => Pastruese) and I need $aUsers = array();

Comment: perfect, that means your array is like this:
$aUsers = array(
        "Agjent për patundshmëri",
        "Elektricist",
        "Moler",
        "Pastruese");